# JavaScript style.visibility doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, visibility

In my aspx page I have a `tr` which is set `visible="false"` by default. But on a selected index of a dropdown I make it `visible="true"`. On the form submit I am validating the control within the `tr` but couldn't find whether the `tr` is visible or not using JavaScript.

My aspx:

```
<tr id="MeasurementTr" runat="server" visible="false">
    <td>
        &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="table_label">
        Measurement</td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DlMeasurement" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

and my JavaScript code,

```
 alert(document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MeasurementTr").style.visibility);
 if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MeasurementTr").style.visibility=="visible"){
     if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DlMeasurement").selectedIndex == 0) {
         document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ErrorMsg").innerHTML = "Please Select Your Measurement";
         document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DlMeasurement").focus();
         return false;
     }
 }
```

But my alert shows nothing. It didn't show `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `visible` property of asp.net does not alter the CSS visibility property.. when it is true, asp.net will not render the element at all on the client side, so you cannot access it..

Use a class with <strike>`visibility:hidden`</strike> `display:none` instead..

***[udpate]***

changed the suggestion to `display:none` after cheeso's comment, since `visibility:hidden` will retain the space the element occupies, while the `display:none` takes no space in the rendered page.. it is, most likely, what you need ...

Comment: Also consider the css display:none style.  It's different from visibbility but may be what you want. http://www.devx.com/tips/tip/13638

Comment: yep, in css, the `display:none` is closer than `visibility:hidden` to the `visible` property of ASPNET.

Answer (score 3):

The [`visible` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#visibility) can take the values `hidden`, `visible` or `collapse`.

`true` and `false` are invalid CSS.

The `.style.*` properties represent *inline* CSS (as specified in the `style` **attribute**). If you set a value using a stylesheet, that will not be reflected in the `.style.*` on the element.

As a rule of thumb, you are usually better off modifying `.className`.

Comment: @David in my selected index changed event i ve given  
`protected void DlMeasurement_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MeasurementTr.Visible = true;`

Comment: @Pandiya, take a look at my answer.. your element does not get rendered at all, so there is nothing to access..

Answer (score -1):

The ASP control that is not visible on the "server side" is not rendered on the "client side" so no MeasurementTr element exists in the HTML. Use view source (or another technique) to see the rendered HTML from the browser.